# Lotus Notes: Sum of hours

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have two editable time/date fields, `TimeIn` and `TimeOut`, and one computed for display field `hoursWorked`, what it does is get the difference between `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` and display it in hours:minutes, e.g (02:30 hrs). I decided to have another editable time/date field`TimeIn_1` and `TimeOut_1` field and computed for display field `hoursWorked` and another computed for display field `totalHours`, which displays the total/sum of hours of  `hoursWorked` and `hoursWorked_1`. I tried this code:

```
thours:=@If(hoursWorked=null | hoursWorked_1=null; @Return(""); "" );
seconds := hoursWorked+hoursWorked_1;
hours := @Integer(seconds/3600);
minutes := @Integer(@Modulo(seconds;3600)/60);
output := @Right("00" + @Text(hours); 2) + ":" + @Right("00" + @Text(minutes); 2);
@TextToTime(output)
```

but nothing happens. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the type of the totalHours field?  And what are you trying to do in the first line of code?  What happens if you remove it?  (BTW: Are you aware that null is not a keyword in Notes formula language?  It acts as a reference to a variable called 'null' -- which in most cases of course is uninitialized, but could in theory have a non-null value.)

Comment: the type for `totalHours` field is text. The first line code is to check if the value of two fields is null, and return the value 0, coz I get an error sometimes, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you calculated your fields `hoursWorked` and `hoursWorked_1` the same way like in this formula shown. If that is the case, the fields `hoursWorked` and `hoursWorked_1` are from type "Date/Time" in document no matter how you define the fields in form.

That's why your formula should look like this:

```
thours:=@If(@IsNull(hoursWorked) | @IsNull(hoursWorked_1); @Return(""); "" );
nullTime := @ToTime("00:00");
seconds := (@ToTime(hoursWorked) - nullTime)+ (@ToTime(hoursWorked_1) - nullTime);
hours := @Integer(seconds/3600);
minutes := @Integer(@Modulo(seconds;3600)/60);
output := @Right("00" + @Text(hours); 2) + ":" + @Right("00" + @Text(minutes); 2);
@TextToTime(output)
```

Only first three lines are different to your formula.

Comment: I tried using your code but still no output. I don't see why.

Comment: I changed third line - please try again. Are `hoursWorked` and `hoursWorked_1` shown in format "hh:mm"?

Comment: Yes. It is shown in "hh:mm" format. Still no result. When I subtract them, it gives a result.

Comment: It depends also on times itself. If the sum of seconds exceeds the max number value then you get an error too (in this case nothing)

Comment: I see now why. But, how can I set it to expand the value it can hold? Like 200 hrs and 59mins?

Comment: @TextToTime allows as a maximum "23:59" if you use the 24 hours format and maybe "12:00" if you use 12 hours format.

Comment: Don't use `@TextToTime`. Calculate values in minutes internally and show the "hh:mm" format as a text without using `@TextToTime`.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much Knut. You're always a help. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad I could help. Good luck with your application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the first test of hoursWorked=null is correct.  I think you need @IsNull(hoursWorked).  That said I would think the result would still be false and the formula would continue.

It might be worthwhile to see just what output produces without the @TextToTime.

Comment: It might be correct, and it probably works correctly. Null is not a keyword, so it is interpreted as a variable (or a field). The variable isn't initialised explicitly, so it is evaluated as having a null value. I couldn't find a clear definition in the Help database for this null value, but for fields it is specified as "". I assume it's the same for variables.